# SustainSys library is not including email claim from Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, identityserver3, kentor-authservices, sustainsys-saml2

I am using IdentityServer3 for authentication and i have also configured `Azure AD` as external provider in IdentityServer3. Since `Azure AD` is using SAML2 protocol i am using [SustainSys](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) library to configure `Azure AD`.
In Azure AD i have configure the payload as below.  Notice the email is included in the payload
[image]

However, after user is authenticated in Azure AD, and request comes back to IdentityServer,  SustainSys library is not including email claim.

[image]

Is there any configuration i need to do in SustainSys library to include email claim? In IdentityServer3 I am loading Azure AD provider using code

```
      private void AddSAML2Idp(IAppBuilder app, SAML2Provider provider, string signInAsType)
        {
            var authenticationOptions = new Saml2AuthenticationOptions(false)
            {
                SPOptions = new SPOptions
                {
                    EntityId = new EntityId(provider.AuduenceURI), // Auduence URI   
                    MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = provider.MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm,
                    ModulePath = string.Format("/{0}", provider.Idp)
                },
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
                AuthenticationType = provider.Idp,
                Caption = provider.Caption
            };

            UseIdSrv3LogoutOnFederatedLogout(app, authenticationOptions);                          
            authenticationOptions.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(LoadCertificateFromWindwosStore(ApplicationConfig.Saml2SigningCertificateSubjectName));

            var identityProvider = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(provider.EntityID), authenticationOptions.SPOptions)
            {                
                MetadataLocation = provider.MetadataLocation,
                LoadMetadata = true 
            };            

            authenticationOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(identityProvider);

            app.UseSaml2Authentication(authenticationOptions);
        }
```

Comment: Use SAML Dev tools for Chrome to capture the SAML message and see if it contains the attribute. If it doesn't it's an Azure AD issue. If it does, it's a Sustainsys.Saml2/IdentityServer issue.

Comment: @AndersAbel Thanks I will use SAML Dev tool to capture SAML. I am curious where is the SAML2 to OpenID claims transformation is done in SustainSys library? Can I override transformation logic?

Comment: All attributes in the incoming assertion are converted to claims. Override the `AcsCommandResulted` notification to modify the created ClaimsPrincipal before it is returned to the calling framework.